# Hide some operations from a product in Azure Api management Service

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying the Azure Api management service.

I have created an Api and added various operations.
I need to publish two different products which exposes selected operations of this Api. Is there a way to achieve that. Currently when I add an Api to a product all the operations are exposed.

Comment: I would also like to see this as well.  We have to create separate API Management accounts to give specialized APIs but not expose them visibly to other clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this scenario is not supported. Please feel free to raise a feature request at: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management

Comment: I have raised the feature request, Thanks

Comment: @djn Is this your feedback post?
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/17283983-api-operation-visibility